# Slow/Delayed movement of CMainFrame

Tags: mfc

I have an MDI Document/View application written in C++ in which each CView contains about 200 CWnd based child windows. Each child window is created with a WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE style. The child window's OnPaint method uses CPaintDC and MoveTo/LineTo functions to draw lines from opposite corners. The child window's OnEraseBkgnd method simply returns TRUE. (This is just a test application developed to investigate the problem with a real application.)

When I move a view or resize a view within the main frame, the application is very responsive. However, when I open 10 or more views and then use the mouse to drag the main frame window across the screen, there is a significant delay. The main frame window moves very slowly, often needing a few seconds to catch up to the position of the mouse. This slow movement occurs even when all the views have been minimized.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this problem? Or even where I should start looking?

Thank you,
Kevin

Edit: A solution that demonstrates the described behavior is available at https://github.com/KevinJoback/MFCApplication4.

Comment: Without a code your question is pointless. One assumption is that your app continues repainting everything even when it should not.

Comment: Thank you. I will try and post the code somewhere. But I am confused why my views can be moved and resized quickly but moving the entire application window is slow.

Comment: First, did you test with a release or a debug build? Makes a lot of difference. However 2000 child windows for every view is too much of an overhead anyway. They all have their own handle and window procedures, called all the time. Do you really need to have child windows created there? After all they do one specific thing, draw on the view's window surface. Couldn't you just perform any drawing/painting in the view instead?

Comment: Otherwise check code efficiency in the CChildWnd::OnPaint(). For example, commenting everything there out, will improve performance significantly? Or try using the Win32-level drawing functions instead of creating/destroying C++ objects. Or cache some resources, for example that pen (which you actually don't use) is created and destroyed for every paint request. You could make it a global variable instead.

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Movement is still slow even with a release build. I use child windows for convenience. Each child needs to handle drawing, cutting, pasting, copying, and sometimes moving and scrolling. A long time ago I had the parent window handle all of that but it was not as convenient. But again, what I cannot understand is that if I make a one view with 2000 child windows I can move both the view and the main frame quickly. But if make 10 views with 200 child windows, moving the main frame within the screen is slow. I am still wondering what the difference is.

Comment: Then maybe try the Spyxx utility. Select ONE of the child windows and check the messages it processes.

Comment: I selected one of the child windows and Spy showed no messages (zero) being received by the child window when I drag the main frame. (The CViews also did not receive any messages when the main frame is being dragged.)

Comment: Run a profiler, see if it will show something obvious. You can also `OutputDebugString()` from `CChildWnd::OnPaint()` to see if someone calls it directly while you are moving the main frame.

Comment: I added OutputDebugString() to numerous methods, e.g., OnSize, OnPaint. No output was generated when I drag the main frame window. From more searching it appears that when dragging, a window receives a WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE message and then enters a moving or sizing loop. Unfortunately I cannot find out what is happening in that loop and thus I cannot figure out how to speed up the process. Thank you to everyone for their suggestions.